# Select different column for each row based on calculated value

Tags: r

The code below is working normally, however I would like to make a modification to the output table. To make it easier I'll insert an image below.

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Friday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3), DR01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3), DR02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2), 
                      DR03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7), DR04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2), DR05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4), 
                      DR06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

All <- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), coef = c(4L, 1L, 6L, 3L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

v1<- df1 %>%
  select(starts_with("DR0")) %>% names %>%
  paste0("coef-",.)

All<-left_join(All, df1, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ coef - .)) %>%
  select(-Week, -DR1) %>%
  rename_at(-c(1:4), ~v1)%>%
  relocate(date1)


> All
      date1      date2 Category coef coef-DR01 coef-DR02 coef-DR03 coef-DR04 coef-DR05 coef-DR06
1 2021-06-28 2021-06-30      FDE    4         0         0        -5        -1        -1         2
2 2021-06-28 2021-06-30      ABC    1         0        -1        -4        -3        -3        -3
3 2021-06-28 2021-07-01      FDE    6         2         0         2         3         1         3
4 2021-06-28 2021-07-01      ABC    3         0         1        -4         1        -1         1
```

Notice by the generated output table above that the value obtained in `coef` is being subtracted from the values of the `DR0` columns of my `df1` dataset. Okay so far.

What I want to do: I would like to not need to show the `coef` subtraction - `DR0` columns as it is being done in the code above, but to show it as follows:

`date2 - date1 = Y`, so in the first case it is `30/06 - 28/06 = 2`, in this case I would like to show only the values of `coef-DR02`, which are `0` and `-1`. Another example is for `01/07`, in this case it is `01/07 - 28/06 = 3`, so I would like to show the values of `coef-DR03`, so the values are `2` and `-4`.

Below is the expected output table.

[image]

Did you get the idea? So, it will always depend on the value obtained by subtracting `date2-date1`. If the result for example is `1`, I use the value of `coef-DR01`, if it is `5`, I use the value obtained from `coef-DR05`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

All %>% 
  mutate(across(date1:date2, as.Date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('coef-'), values_to = 'coef-DR') %>% 
  filter(date2 - date1 == as.numeric(str_sub(name, -2))) %>% 
  select(-name)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   date1      date2      Category  coef `coef-DR`
#>   <date>     <date>     <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 2021-06-28 2021-06-30 FDE          4         0
#> 2 2021-06-28 2021-06-30 ABC          1        -1
#> 3 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 FDE          6         2
#> 4 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 ABC          3        -4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks you so much for the reply. In the output table there was name `value`, but I would like to put another name, is this possible? I would like to put `coef-DR` instead of `value`.

Comment: You can change the default name using `values_to` in `pivot_longer`. I've edited the answer.